# C++ / Diamond inheritance / Static Variables

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, diamond-problem

I am facing some design problems, I would like to write:

```
class A { ... };
class B : public A { static string type_; ... };
class C : public A { static string type_; ... };
class D : public B, public C { static string type_; ... };
```

I think up to the definition of class C, i won't have any problems.. but what will happen when i define class D? Since D will inherit from both B and C, i will probably have something ambiguous. My ultimate goal would be to have in each classes B, C and D a static variable which would have the same name, but a different value. Is that possible?

Many thanks in advance
Sed

Comment: @thkala: Trying out stuff can be useful, but it can only tell you what happens on a current implementation. It cannot tell you what was *supposed* to happen or if the result is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

The code you have here is perfectly fine.  Classes are allowed to define members with whatever names they want, even if they match the name of a member in a parent class.  The only time you'll run into trouble is if *using* one of those names would lead to an ambiguity.

In your case, having three `static` data members in the classes `B`, `C`, and `D` will not cause any problems and each class's instance of `type_` will be distinct from all the others.  Just because they have the same name doesn't mean that C++ treats them as overrides; only `virtual` member functions can be overridden.

Within the context of each class and its member functions, any references to `name_` will always refer to the `name_` from that class, since classes hide names from any of their base classes and so the compiler will only look in the current class.  Globally, you can refer to the `name_` fields with their fully-qualified names, like `A::name_`, `B::name_`, etc.

More importantly, the type of inheritance you use here, whether virtual or non-virtual, does not matter because all that's at issue here is the naming of the variables.  Since there's only one copy of each `static` data member, whether your class `D` ends up inheriting two copies of `A::name_` isn't of any concern; it *can't* inherit two copies since only one exists.

Comment: Thank you templatetypedef for having taken the time to give an explanation of the underlying mechanisms, i was a bit lost and convinced it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing ambiguous at all there. You will be able to refer to both fields as `B::type_` and `C::type_`.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `type_` in a method in `D`, it will resolve to `D`'s `type_`. If you write `A::name_` or `B::name_`, it will resolve to the respective instance's `type_`.

On a different note, it seems as if you might be trying to hack some kind of reflection system onto C++, since you have static fields called `type_` in each class. That might be useful under some rare circumstances, but it's probably a bad idea.

Comment: The `type_` variables are all `static`, so individual instances of the different objects will not have any copies of the fields.  They're just globals scoped inside of the respective classes and don't participate in class layout.

Comment: I hadn't seen they were `static`. I have changed my answer now.

Answer (score -1):

In diamond inheritance there is one solution provided by C++ standard to avoid something ambiguous.

Your structure of class definition looks likes like

```
                       A
                      /  \
                     /    \
                    /      \
                   B        C
                    \      /
                     \    /
                      \  /
                       D
```

Now when you inherit class A in class B use following

```
class B : public virtual A
```

Same things for class C.

So when any class inherit from class B & C then it will have just one instance of class A.

No need to virtual inherit for class D. It has no effect.

Size of class D may be same as before but any address of variable access from class B & class C will be same when you create instance of D.

Comment: -1 This is a good description of virtual inheritance, but I don't think it answers the question being asked here.

Comment: Thanks anyway, i was aware of the virtual inheritance mode but it wasn't my question indeed. Sed